# Trying to connect to iCloud but nothing happens

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, icloud

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2012 13" non-retina display running macOS High Sierra. I am trying to connect to iCloud to retrieve some files saved on my iCloud 
Drive.

When I try to connect to iCloud by entering my username and password, but nothing happens. I get no error message or anything. I tried using iCloud and Internet Accounts from the System Preferences panel and the only difference is that if I try to add it from Internet Accounts, it shows up for a few seconds and then disappears.

It all started because I could not select iCloud keychain under the stuff I wanted to synchronize so I signed out. When I try to sign back in this started happening.

I thought it may be due to a network issue but I have tried both wireless and wired connections but I cannot get past this step. I have checked the status of the Apple Services status page and they all show up as online for me.

I have tried the steps listed on this article but none has worked: http://osxdaily.com/2016/10/23/fix-icloud-unknown-error-cant-connect-problem-mac/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried logging in to icloud.com to make sure your password still works?

Comment: @fsb yes i can do that, if i try to login in the browser it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was tired of trying everything so i formatted the hard drive and re installed OSX. That fixed it.